# Fetching a cached Eloquent collection of 10 items times out

Tags: laravel, redis

I'm building a search functionality that returns large collections which are paginated using a LengthAwarePaginator.  I'm trying to cache results using a key called $searchFilter_$query_$offsetPages for a single page of returned results (10 items).  It goes into the cache just fine.  However, it times out when I try to check using Cache::has($key) or fetch using Cache::get($key).

The same problem occurs in the browser as well as in artisan Tinker.  Strangely, when I put a random set of 10 items into the cache in Tinker and fetch them back, everything works fine.  I'm using Redis as the cache driver.

Here is my controller method:

```
public function search($filter, $query, $layout, Request $request) {
  if($layout == "list-map") {
    return view("list-map")->with(['filter' => $filter, 'query' => $query, 'layout' => 'list-map']);      
  } else {
    $offsetPages = $request->input('page', 1) - 1;
    $cacheKey = $filter . "_" . $query . "_" . $offsetPages;

    if(Cache::has($cacheKey)) {
      \Log::info("fetching results from cache");
      $data = Cache::get($cacheKey);

      $totalCt = $data[0];
      $results = $data[1];
    } else {
      $results = $this->getResults($filter, $query);
      $totalCt = $results->count();
      $results = $results->slice($offsetPages, $this->resultsPerPage);

      \Log::info("caching results");
      Cache::put($cacheKey, [$totalCt, $results], 5);
    }

  $results = new LengthAwarePaginator($results,
    $totalCt,
    $this->resultsPerPage,
    $request->input('page', 1),
    ['path' => LengthAwarePaginator::resolveCurrentPath()]
  );

    return view($layout)->with(['filter' => $filter, 'query' => $query, 'layout' => $layout, 'results' => $results]);
  }

}
```

Comment: What content has `$filter`? Maybe build a hash of it to prevent using not allowed characters for a cache key.

Comment: $filter is either "doctor", "clinic", or "all"

Comment: And what about `$query`?

Comment: Also $query does not contain spaces.  They were replaced by underscores in a route closure and then redirected to this controller method.

Comment: dd($cacheKey) => doctor_substance_abuse_0

Answer (score 1):

So, the issue was that many of the models in the collection returned from my getResults() method were obtained via relationship queries.  When I would dd($results) on the single page of 10 results, I could see that there was a "relations" field on each model.  Inside that array were thousands of recursively related models based on the relationship I originally queried.  I was unable to find any information about an option to not eager load these related models.  Instead I came up with a bit of a hacky workaround to fetch the models directly:

```
  $results = $results->slice($offsetPages, $this->resultsPerPage);

      //load models directly so they don't include related models.
      $temp = new \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;
      foreach($results as $result) {
        if(get_class($result) == "App\Doctor") {
          $result = Doctor::find($result->id);
        } else if(get_class($result == "App\Organization")) {
          $result = Organization::find($result->id);
        }
        $temp->push($result);
      }
      $results = $temp;

      \Log::info("caching results");
      Cache::put($cacheKey, [$totalCt, $results], 5);
```

If anyone knows the best practice in this situation, please let me know.  Thanks!

Edit:
I've found a better solution instead of the above workaround.  If I query my relationships like this: $taxonomy->doctors()->get() rather than $taxonomy->doctors, it does not load in the huge recusive relations.

Comment: It is a rare use case, but maybe `$model->newQueryWithoutRelationships()` is suitable for this task (when querying the results, to not load the relations at all). You can also unload a relation with `$model->unsetRelation('doctor')` after they were loaded (which doesn't make much sense). I thinkt hat if you optimize your query, you don't need caching at all...

Comment: I'm not really sure how I would optimize it since it requires querying multiple tables, sometimes two levels deep via relationships to fetch meaningful search results.  Thank you for the suggestions!

Comment: You could also build a query with joins manually, if you don't need multiple child rows of a relation. Maybe this is something for another question. ;)

Comment: That might be ideal, but I'm content with the current state of it.  I need to move the project forward.  Thank you for your insight.

Answer (score 0):

I dont really see why your code doesn't work. The only potential problems I see are the cache keys, which could contain problematic characters, as well as the way you check for a cached value. As you are using `Cache::has($key)` before `Cache::get($key)`, you could end up with a race condition where the first call returns `true` and the latter `null` because the cached value timed out just between the two calls.

I tried to address both issues in the following snippet:

```
public function search($filter, $query, $layout, Request $request)
{
    if($layout == "list-map") {
        return view("list-map")->with(['filter' => $filter, 'query' => $query, 'layout' => 'list-map']);      
    } else {
        $offsetPages = $request->input('page', 1) - 1;
        $cacheKey = md5("{$filter}_{$query}_{$offsetPages}");
        $duration = 5; // todo: make this configurable or a constant

        [$totalCount, $results] = Cache::remember($cacheKey, $duration, function () use ($filter, $query) {
            $results = $this->getResults($filter, $query);
            $totalCount = $results->count();
            $filteredResults = $results->slice($offsetPages, $this->resultsPerPage);

            return [$totalCount, $filteredResults];
        });

        $results = new LengthAwarePaginator($results,
            $totalCount,
            $this->resultsPerPage,
            $request->input('page', 1),
            ['path' => LengthAwarePaginator::resolveCurrentPath()]
        );

        return view($layout)->with(compact('filter', 'query', 'layout', 'results'));
    }
}
```

The inbuilt function `Cache::remember()` doesn't use `Cache::has()` under the hood. Instead, it will simply call `Cache::get()`. As this function will return `null` as default if no cache was hit, the function can easily determine if it has to execute the closure or not.

I also wrapped the `$cacheKey` in `md5()`, which gives a consistently valid key.

---

Looking at the following part of your code

```
$results = $this->getResults($filter, $query);
$totalCount = $results->count();
$filteredResults = $results->slice($offsetPages, $this->resultsPerPage);
```

I am quite sure the whole search could be improved (independently of the caching). Because it seems you are loading all results for a specific search into memory, even if you *throw away* most parts of it. There is certainly a better way to do this.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback.  I'll see if hashing the key makes any difference.  I did try using the remember function at first, but I think I ran into an issue calling $this->getResults() since I believe $this would be out of scope inside the closure.  I tried setting it to $self before and passing it in with use, but I think there were still issues with that.

Comment: I just tried changing the condition to if(!is_null($data = Cache::get($cacheKey))) instead of using has followed by get.  The problem still remains.

Comment: hashing the key did not make a difference either.

Comment: Ah, it's something to do with the collection I'm returning.  When I simply take the first 500 records, slice, and cache, it works fine.  I'll continue to investigate what I'm returning from $this->getResults().  I'll let you know what I find out.  Thanks.

Comment: The problem is that I'm getting most of the models in the collection via relationships and it's loading in everything related to each model.  So, when I dd() and inspect a model, there is a "relations" array that holds all related models.  Is there a way to not include these related models?